# How execute code after returning result in Play framework

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.3

How execute code after returning result to client?
Example:

```
return ok("first");
```

After that I need send response to my websocket actor

```
myActor.tell("second",null)
```

Main goal - I need send message to socket after sending response

Comment: Why do you need to send the message after the return?

Comment: Sometimes client receives websocket message before restful response. I need avoid that problem for client's purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it directly, as `return` statements ends the action.

If problem is too long rendering of the template, you can render it first, then send the message and finally send pre-rendered Result, like

```
Result res = ok("first");
myActor.tell("second",null);
return res;
```

If it doesn't satisfy you still, you can use Akka scheduler to schedule the message with let's say 1 second delay. (check Akka's documentations for details)

Finally you can send content and message at once within the current Result i.e. wrapping it within JSON object, or adding the message as a response header - of course if you're handling it with JS on the client side.

Answer (score 1):

How about [Action Composition](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/JavaActionsComposition)?

In Java the action composition class could like like this:

```
public class WebSocketAction extends play.mvc.Action.Simple {
    public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        Promise<SimpleResult> call = delegate.call(ctx);
        // Do your websocket stuff here
        return call;
    }
}
```

And then just annotate your action method with `@With(WebSocketAction.class)`.